# Text still exists after the position of ifstream::gcount()

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I wrote a text file, then read the file to a string buffer larger than the text file.

I thought there would be no text after the position of `ifstream::gcount()` because the buffer was initialized with `\0`s.

But there *was* text. How is this possible?

example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::string path = "test.txt";

    // write to file
    std::ofstream out(path);    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10'000; ++i) {
        std::string lineNum = std::to_string(i);
        out << lineNum + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + lineNum + "\n"; 
    } 
    out.close(); // (Just FYI: without close(), the result changes, although ofstream and ifstream are being used separately and they support RAII.)

    // read from file
    std::ifstream in(path); 
    std::string buffer;
    int bufferSize = 1'000'000; 
    buffer.resize(bufferSize); 
    in.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size()); 

    auto gc = in.gcount(); 
    auto found = buffer.find('\n', gc); 
    std::string substr = buffer.substr(gc - 10, 100); 

    std::cout << "gcount: " << gc << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "found: " << found << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "npos?: " << std::boolalpha << (found == std::string::npos) << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "substr:\n" << substr << std::endl;    
}
```

result:

```
gcount: 237788
found: 237810
npos?: false    // I thought `found` should be the same as `string::npos`.
substr:         
xxxx10000
01xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9601     // I thought there should be no text after `gcount()`.
9602xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9602
9603xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9603
9604xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

---

Executed with MSVC for 32bit, on Windows(x64).

P.S. Also tried building for 64bit, but the same result.
(used `in.read(const_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size());` instead of `in.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());`)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/438754c10d9b5973).  Please provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I checked your result and it's different from mine. I built the code with MSVC 32bit, on 64bit Windows. Does this difference in the system/compiler can make the result of this code different?

Comment: `std::ifstream in(path);` should be `std::ifstream in(path, std::ios_base::binary);`

Comment: @john Thank you so much, now I got the culprit. Didn't think it's related to CRLF - that's why MilesBudnek couldn't reproduce the problem. I'll post about this as an answer just for newbies like me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@john's comment saved me.

The culprit was how the different OSs interpret the new line character differently.

If opened with a hex editor, we can see the difference.

If run the code in the question in Windows, the file written by the code shows `0x0D 0x0A`, which is simply `\r\n`. But, in Unix or Unix-like OS such as Linux, it would be just `0x0A`, which means `\n`.

But, if we use the `std::ios_base::binary` option when using `std::fstream`, the OS will *not* interpret the newline character, but just use it "as-is".
So, with that option, a hex editor would show only `0x0A` regardless of OS.

So using the `ios_base::binary` option with `ofstream` or `ifstream` or both get rid of the problem described in the question.